# Dual Boot System, Slow Boot into Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, boot-repair

I have a dual boot system with a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.  Both OSes worked beautifully and booted up perfectly.  I've been having issues with Clonezilla, long story don't ask, and pulled the installation media too soon during shutdown.  My Grub menu was ruined but I was able to repair the system using boot repair, Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 are back.  However, the issue is Ubuntu 20.04 now takes about 2 minutes to open.

Here are the results of systemd-analyze

```
Startup finished in 8.600s (firmware) + 3.764s (loader) + 33.965s (kernel) + 1min 35.755s (userspace) = 2min 22.085s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 35.745s in userspace
```

Here are the results of systemd-analyze blame:

```
5.113s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                    
1.435s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-116.mount                       
1.430s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount                       
1.402s snap-kate-64.mount                                            
1.341s snap-sqlitebrowser-1864.mount                                 
1.299s snap-core18-1705.mount                                        
1.265s fwupd.service                                                 
1.222s snap-gimp-252.mount                                           
1.168s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-27.mount                        
1.109s snap-kde\x2dframeworks\x2d5\x2dqt\x2d5\x2d14\x2dcore18-4.mount
1.104s snap-vlc-1397.mount                                           
 889ms snap-sqlitebrowser-1894.mount                                 
 887ms snap-vlc-1620.mount                                           
 709ms dev-loop1.device                                              
 686ms snap-blender-37.mount                                         
 682ms snap-chromium-1123.mount                                      
 674ms snap-postman-107.mount                                        
 673ms snap-snapd-7264.mount                                         
 660ms dev-loop2.device                                              
 649ms dev-sda1.device                                               
 611ms dev-loop3.device                                              
 582ms dev-loop4.device                                              
 570ms systemd-logind.service                                        
 567ms dev-loop6.device                                              
 519ms bolt.service                                                  
 493ms dev-loop5.device                                              
 425ms dev-loop0.device                                              
 391ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-24.mount                        
 387ms snap-snap\x2dstore-433.mount                                  
 365ms snapd.service                                                 
 340ms systemd-journald.service                                      
 334ms dev-loop8.device                                              
 318ms snap-core18-1754.mount                                        
 316ms upower.service                                                
 290ms dev-loop10.device                                             
 278ms dev-loop9.device                                              
 255ms systemd-resolved.service                                      
 244ms snap-core-9066.mount                                          
 240ms systemd-timesyncd.service                                     
 228ms networkd-dispatcher.service                                   
 212ms snap-code-31.mount                                            
 210ms dev-loop13.device                                             
 202ms dev-loop7.device                                              
 198ms accounts-daemon.service                                       
 193ms udisks2.service                                               
 173ms systemd-journal-flush.service                                 
 164ms snap-chromium-1135.mount                                      
 134ms dev-loop11.device                                             
 126ms dev-loop15.device                                             
 125ms dev-loop16.device                                             
 120ms avahi-daemon.service                                          
 118ms bluetooth.service                                             
 116ms NetworkManager.service                                        
 112ms polkit.service                                                
 105ms dev-loop14.device                                             
 105ms dev-loop17.device                                             
  97ms systemd-rfkill.service                                        
  92ms switcheroo-control.service                                    
  86ms thermald.service                                              
  84ms wpa_supplicant.service                                        
  83ms user@125.service                                              
  82ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                                  
  80ms dev-loop18.device                                             
  75ms user@1000.service                                             
  73ms apport.service                                                
  69ms ModemManager.service                                          
  68ms gpu-manager.service                                           
  62ms grub-common.service                                           
  61ms systemd-udevd.service                                         
  58ms secureboot-db.service                                         
  54ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4A81\x2d6B49.service         
  52ms keyboard-setup.service                                        
  49ms dev-loop12.device                                             
  44ms e2scrub_reap.service                                          
  42ms grub-initrd-fallback.service                                  
  42ms geoclue.service                                               
  39ms apparmor.service                                              
  34ms rsyslog.service                                               
  30ms gdm.service                                                   
  27ms kerneloops.service                                            
  25ms dev-loop19.device                                             
  25ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                                
  24ms snapd.apparmor.service                                        
  22ms nvidia-persistenced.service                                   
  21ms systemd-modules-load.service                                  
  20ms plymouth-start.service                                        
  19ms systemd-user-sessions.service                                 
  19ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                                
  18ms pppd-dns.service                                              
  17ms binfmt-support.service                                        
  17ms boot-efi.mount                                                
  15ms modprobe@drm.service                                          
  13ms colord.service                                                
  13ms snapd.seeded.service                                          
  13ms systemd-sysusers.service                                      
  13ms alsa-restore.service                                          
  13ms plymouth-read-write.service                                   
  11ms systemd-remount-fs.service                                    
  11ms systemd-random-seed.service                                   
  11ms dev-loop20.device                                             
  11ms systemd-sysctl.service                                        
  10ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service               
  10ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                                 
  10ms user-runtime-dir@125.service                                  
  10ms dev-hugepages.mount                                           
   9ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount                                 
   9ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                            
   9ms dev-mqueue.mount                                              
   9ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                                        
   8ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                                      
   8ms systemd-update-utmp.service                                   
   7ms console-setup.service                                         
   7ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                          
   6ms systemd-backlight@backlight:nvidia_0.service                  
   6ms kmod-static-nodes.service                                     
   5ms ufw.service                                                   
   3ms openvpn.service                                               
   3ms rtkit-daemon.service                                          
   3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                                 
   2ms setvtrgb.service                                              
   1ms sys-kernel-config.mount                                       
 644us snapd.socket
```

Here is systemd-analyze critical-chain

```
graphical.target @1min 35.745s
└─multi-user.target @1min 35.745s
  └─unattended-upgrades.service @1min 31.085s
    └─systemd-logind.service @1min 30.513s +570ms
      └─basic.target @1min 30.469s
        └─sockets.target @1min 30.469s
          └─snapd.socket @1min 30.469s +644us
            └─sysinit.target @1min 30.464s
              └─systemd-backlight@backlight:nvidia_0.service @1min 32.170s +6ms
                └─system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice @922ms
                  └─system.slice @228ms
                    └─-.slice @228ms
```

How can I get this back to a working state?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I was able to fix this issue.  I had to go into boot log located at:

/var/log/boot.log

There were repeated calls to a

```
A start job is running for
```

UUID 4a4d5c2b-cfe1-4ad2-8ebe-49940aaee855

I went into fstab (File System Table) located at /etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=246a96fa-1f09-4d82-9488-792c05ba971a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
#UUID=4A81-6B49  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
#UUID=4a4d5c2b-cfe1-4ad2-8ebe-49940aaee855 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=4A81-6B49  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
```

There are two things you can see here.  The swap is located on UUID 4a4d5c2b-cfe1-4ad2-8ebe-49940aaee855 and I have commented it out.  In the process of rescuing my dual boot system this fstab table was probably regenerated or it no longer matches the current table layout and this entry is now invalid.

That makes sense because in the process of rescuing my system I had to use GParted to recreate the swap outside of my Ubuntu 20.04 installation.

Based on my internet searches I commented this out so systemd can mount it automatically.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=201816

Here are the current results of systemd-analyze:

```
Startup finished in 8.603s (firmware) + 11.918s (loader) + 33.977s (kernel) + 7.229s (userspace) = 1min 1.728s 
graphical.target reached after 7.220s in userspace
```

Hope this helps someone else down the line!

Comment: The PROPER fix is to use `sudo blkid | grep -i swap` to obtain the NEW UUID of your new swap partition, and then edit that into /etc/fstab. (or switch to a /swapfile). Commenting out the swap in your /etc/fstab just disables swap, and ALL systems need swap.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't sense.  You're telling me my system now has no swap and that the info I found on https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=201816 is incorrect because systemd DOES NOT mount swap automatically.  So what exactly is ```sudo blkid | grep -i swap``` supposed to show me at this point?

Comment: Sorry but this is not even correct. I tried your suggest and here are the results from systemd-analyze.  Thanks for your review but I will revert to the solution that works:

```
Startup finished in 8.621s (firmware) + 3.719s (loader) + 34.012s (kernel) + 1min 35.582s (userspace) = 2min 21.935s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 35.573s in userspace
```

Comment: Not like you're going to listen... if you show me `sudo blkid` and `free -h` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` maybe I'll change my comments... maybe I'll clarify my comments... or maybe I won't. I'm not here to argue.

Comment: Why wouldn't I listen?  As you can see I tried your suggestion.  In fact the PROPER way to diagnose a problem is to get more info.  If I have time tomorrow maybe I'll try your suggestion, maybe I won't... but since I got the UUID already and updated fstab I probably won't.

Comment: You're correct. The PROPER way to diagnose a problem is to get more info. After your earlier (rather hostile) comments, my LAST comment was to try and get more info. You haven't given me that info.

Comment: re: *"since I got the UUID already and updated fstab"* sounds like you already did my first comment.