# Ubuntu 22.04 slow startup in Dual Boot Setup

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, 22.04, startup, boot-repair

So I have been facing a problem with my laptop running Ubuntu 22.04 (18.04 until recently) on a dual boot setup. Problem is that Ubuntu takes a very long time to startup (I get the login screen after around 8-10 mins of selecting Ubuntu from the GRUB menu, followed by a black screen for 1-2 mins. Also, all apps take a long time to launch for the first time after every boot.)

My system and setup details are:

- Lenovo Legion Y540
- Storage - 256 GB SSD, 1 TB HDD
- RAM / Processor - 8 GB RAM / Intel i7 9th Gen
- Graphics - NVIDIA 1650 4 GB
- Manufacturer installed Windows 10 on SSD.
- I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on the HDD (recently upgraded it to 22.04) (The problem was same in both versions).

Ubuntu installation details on HDD:

- Partitioned 150 GB space on the HDD and installed ubuntu there. A 538 MB FAT "EFI System" partition was automatically made during installation.

Boot log obtained by `journalctl -b`  can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fFTqvmBto9TBEDcIglkIn-1y4p1ZjC6J/view?usp=sharing).

Output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`

```
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @2min 868ms
└─multi-user.target @2min 868ms
  └─plymouth-quit-wait.service @56.942s +1min 3.925s
    └─systemd-user-sessions.service @56.784s +118ms
      └─network.target @56.741s
        └─NetworkManager.service @46.457s +10.283s
          └─dbus.service @46.453s
            └─basic.target @46.287s
              └─sockets.target @46.287s
                └─snapd.socket @46.281s +3ms
                  └─sysinit.target @45.984s
                    └─systemd-timesyncd.service @45.718s +264ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @44.386s +1.283s
                        └─systemd-journal-flush.service @11.994s +32.372s
                          └─systemd-remount-fs.service @11.773s +203ms
                            └─systemd-journald.socket @11.610s
                              └─system.slice @11.576s
                                └─-.slice @11.576s
```

I have gone through posts on different forums looking for a fix but none of the answers seemed to point to the cause (and conclusivley a real solution).

I wanted to try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1235759) but noticed that my system has no swap file indicated by the contents of `etc/fstab` file below:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=52bdb66e-da04-4b5a-ab4b-cae53b34baa2 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=06A8-188D  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-hp_v210w_AA00000000016327-0:0 /mnt/usb-hp_v210w_AA00000000016327-0:0 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Waiting 8-10 minutes for startup, and then waiting for 1-2 minutes for every application to launch is a huge pain. Please suggest solution to fix this problem.

Comment: Any update on this? I've run into a very similar problem since a few days.

Answer (score 0):

After corrections in the `/etc/fstab` file, grub needs to be updated.

If this is not done, then most often a long download occurs because of this.

```
sudo update-grub
sudo update-grub2
```

Comment: This is not an answer as grub update updates grub and has nothing to do with fstab

Comment: You can even do this with `update-initramfs`, but if you don't do anything, you will most likely get long download.